# Setting AutocompleteMode to Suggest doesn't have an effect

Tags: winforms, combobox, autocomplete, entity-framework-6, bindingsource

I have few comboboxes. I initialize their datasources through binding sources (I use EF6). My Combobox Tasks looks like this:

[image: combobox tasks image]

So, when I set AutoCompleteMode property to Suggested, the auto complete doesn't work. The weird thing, is that I have two another comboboxes, with (I would say) the exact same setup, and they work...The autocompletion works on them.

How to debug this?

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to set the `AutoCompleteSource` property to `AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource` (which is mandatory).

Comment: @Jimi Oh what a silly error I made. Yes it was it. You can answer the question, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up a `ComboBox` that automatically completes the user's input string, we need to configure  3 different properties. A description from the Docs:

> Use the `AutoCompleteCustomSource`, `AutoCompleteMode`, and
>   `AutoCompleteSource` properties to create a `ComboBox` that
>   automatically completes input strings by comparing the prefix being
>   entered to the prefixes of all strings in a maintained source

[AutoCompleteCustomSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletecustomsource?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource);k(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2): the specialized collection of items that provides the source of the Autocomplete strings.
[AutoCompleteMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode?view=netframework-4.7.2): defines how the input auto-completion is performed.
[AutoCompleteSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autocompletesource?view=netframework-4.7.2): specifies which is the source of the completion functionality.

The latter could be the `FileSystem`, using the Files or Directories lists in a defined path, the `RecentUsedItems`, `HistoryList` URLs or, as in this case, [AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autocompletesource?view=netframework-4.7.2), indicating that the source list of items for the completion is provided by an [AutoCompleteStringCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autocompletestringcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) which can be specified assigning the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` property a `AutoCompleteStringCollection` or another compatible source (a `List` for example, since this collection implements the `IEnumerable` and `IList` interfaces).